# Converting NetCDF dataset array to GeoTiff using rasterio Python

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf, rasterio, rioxarray

I have read a NetCDF file using the `netCDF4` library and then read one of its datasets ("Evapotranspiration") into a variable (variable contains array) using the following code. Subsequently now I am trying to convert this array into a GeoTIFF file using `rasterio`. However, the resulting GeoTIFF is appearing to be rotated by 90 Degrees when I am opening it in QGIS. Following is my code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import rasterio
from rasterio.transform import from_origin

nc = Dataset(r'D:\Weather data\et_01012018.nc','r')
 
lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
et = nc.variables['Evapotranspiration'][:]

transform = from_origin(68.175 , 37.025 , 0.05, 0.05)

profile = {'driver': 'GTiff', 'height': et.shape[1], 'width': et.shape[0], 'count': 1, 'dtype': str(et.dtype), 'transform': transform}
with rasterio.open(r'D:\Weather data\test.tif', 'w', crs='EPSG:4326', **profile) as dst:
     dst.write(et,1)
```

Further I also tried GDAL to implement the same but no success as of now. I am getting same results i.e. the raster file is rotated by 90 degrees in clockwise direction. Following is the code implemented by using GDAL:

```
import gdal, osr
from netCDF4 import Dataset

nc = Dataset(r'D:\Weather data\et_01012018.nc','r')
lat = nc.variables['latitude'][:]
lon = nc.variables['longitude'][:]
et = nc.variables['Evapotranspiration'][:]

# reverse array so the tif looks like the array
et_T = et[::-1] 
cols = et_T.shape[1]
rows = et_T.shape[0]

# Origin should be in Longitude-Latitude form
originX = 79
originY = 21

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
outRaster = driver.Create(r'D:\Weather data\test.tif', cols, rows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float64)
outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, 0.05, 0, originY, 0, 0.05))
outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(et_T)
outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
outRasterSRS.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
outband.FlushCache()
outRaster = None
```

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Does this also happen if you use a GeoTIFF as input data?

Comment: @Bugmenot123 I haven't tried it....will try and see....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/index.html) for your dataset.

You can open your dataset like so:

```py
import rioxarray
import xarray

xds = xarray.open_dataset('D:\Weather data\et_01012018.nc')
```

If your CRS is not discovered, you should be able to add it like so:

```py
xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)
```

Then, you should be able to create a geotiff from the `Evapotranspiration` like so:

```py
xds["Evapotranspiration"].rio.to_raster('D:\Weather data\test.tif')
```

If this does not produce the correct results, I would be interested in learning more about your input file data.

Comment: Hi @snowman2....thanks for your reply. Ur solution is working fine for me. In some of the NC files "InvalidDimensionOrder" error is coming which I think is the issue while creating the NC files. As a solution I am transposing the dataset and the issue is getting resolved.

Comment: Great, I am glad to hear that this solution works out of the box.

Comment: @snowman2 it looks to me that it will only work if your longitude and latitude coordinates are already defined with an affine transform, am I correct? I am looking for an example with irregular grid

Comment: This example only works with a regular grid. If you have an irregular grid, that usually means that your data was projected into another projection. The solution in that case is to convert your data back into the original projection with a regular grid.

Comment: If that is not the case, then you will need to resample your data onto a regular grid for this to work.

Comment: Nice answer but the library is buggy. It has syntax and import errors!

Comment: Are you using python 3.7+? It doesn't support older versions of python.

Comment: Hi @snowman2. Can you tell why this code is not working with this file "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zw8kSPZPRIu_YDxixIlOByPCY19GNMbz/view?usp=sharing"

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the variable et by

```
import numpy as np

et = np.rot90(et,2)
et = np.flip(et,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone arriving here from Google, it does appear that rasterio does read netCDF files such that the data is transposed and rotated from the typical reading of GeoTiffs.

Comment: Mind editing your answer to say that you can use `rioxarray.open_rasterio` to use `rasterio` to transpose/rotate the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can read [nc file directly with rasterio.](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasets.html)

```
import rasterio as rio
var = "Evapotranspiration"
reader = rio.open(r"netcdf:Path\to\nc_file\nc_file.nc:"+var)
prof = reader.profile
prof.update(driver='GTiff', crs="EPSG:4326",)
array = reader.read(1)
with rio.open(rf"Path\to\new_tiff_file\new_tif.tif", "w", **prof) as dst:
    dst.write(array,1)
```