# Reading CRS and Affine transformation from a NetCDF with CF conventions

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, netcdf, rasterio, affine-transformation

I have a NetCDF with geographical information. I'd like to obtain a GeoTIFF file with `rasterio`. The problem is how to translate the geographical information from CF standard to something that GeoTIFF can understand.

In the netCDF I have this variable:

```
int projection_lambert ;
    projection_lambert:grid_mapping_name = "lambert_conformal_conic" ;
    projection_lambert:latitude_of_projection_origin = 63. ;
    projection_lambert:longitude_of_central_meridian = 15. ;
    projection_lambert:standard_parallel = 63., 63. ;
    projection_lambert:proj4 = "+proj=lcc +lat_0=63 +lon_0=15 +lat_1=63 +lat_2=63 +no_defs +R=6.371e+06" ;
```

Therefore I can create the CRS with:

```
crs = CRS.from_proj4("+proj=lcc +lat_0=63 +lon_0=15 +lat_1=63 +lat_2=63 +no_defs +R=6.371e+06")
```

OK, I know the projection, but what is missing is the *Affine transformation*. This information is implicitly stored in the `lat` and `lon` variables the NetCDF also includes, but I'm not sure how to go from there, to the Affine transformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NetCDF dataset array to GeoTiff using rasterio Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317/converting-netcdf-dataset-array-to-geotiff-using-rasterio-python)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/corteva/rioxarray/

https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/convert_to_raster.html

```py
import rioxarray

rds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(...)
rds.rio.to_raster(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import xarray as xr

var_name = 'name'
nc_file = xr.open_dataset('/path/to/nc/file.nc')
var = nc_file[var_name]

# Get affine as affine.Affine object
aff = var.rio.transform()
# Get x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max bounds
bou = var.rio.bounds()
```