# NetCDF4 file to raster with Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, netcdf, rioxarray

I am trying to read NetCDF4 files from data developed by Toshicika Iizumi (https://doi.pangaea.de/10.1594/PANGAEA.909132) on global crop yields. I would like to turn the data into a form that is readable by ArcGIS Pro since ArcGIS doesn't recognize the NetCDF4 format.

I am reading the file with xarray like this...

```
import rioxarray
import xarray
fn = ".../yield_2012.nc4"
xds = xarray.open_dataset(fn)
xds
```

[image: The output looks like this]

There doesn't seem to be any information on the projection.

How can I turn this into a raster or GeoTIFF for use in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: Did you try the 'Make netCDF Raster Layer' tool in the geoprocessing section? This way ArcGIS Pro can convert and thus read the file. see: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/multidimension/make-netcdf-raster-layer.htm

Comment: I tried `import arcpy
fn = "yield_2016.nc4"
arcpy.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer_md(fn, "var",
                         "lon","lat","yield")` but it doesn't seem like that worked. I also tried the geoprocessing tool and I can't see the nc4 file format in the directory.

Comment: The output should be in the default geodatabase if you run your command. Did you check there?

Comment: If you wish to also ask about QGIS then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting NetCDF dataset array to GeoTiff using rasterio Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317/converting-netcdf-dataset-array-to-geotiff-using-rasterio-python)

Comment: You can convert a netcdf to a geotiff with gdal. In gdal to convert nc to tiff:
`gdal_translate -of GTiff Mynetcdf.nc MyTifOutput.tiff`

and if you know which projection it should be in, you can add the projection like so
`gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 MyUnprojectedTif.tiff MyProjectedOutput.tiff`  -- eg to add EPSG4326 projection.      

These can be combined to one line.

Gdal can be run in python, the syntax will be a little different, you'll have to check that.