# Cannot use PROJ4 with gdal.Translate in Python

Tags: python, gdal, hdf5

I'm trying to convert [MCD12Q1](https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODV6_Cmp_C/MOTA/MCD12Q1.006/2001.01.01/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330.hdf) HDF5 product to GeoTiff. I extracted metadata from the file, and from this [user guide](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/documents/101/MCD12_User_Guide_V6.pdf) I found the projection information as

> PROJ4: '+proj=sinu +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m'

However, when I tried to use these variables in my Python script:

```
from osgeo import gdal
    
Dataset     = gdal.Open("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330.hdf", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
SubDatasets = Dataset.GetSubDatasets()
SubLayers   = [SubLayer for SubLayer, _ in SubDatasets]

SubLayer    = gdal.Open(SubLayers[0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
SLName      = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()['long_name']
print(SLName)

WestCoord   = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["WESTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"]
NorthCoord  = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"]
EastCoord   = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["EASTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"]
SouthCoord  = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["SOUTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"]
PROJ4       = "+proj=sinu +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m"

Command     = f"-a_srs '{PROJ4}' -a_ullr {WestCoord} {NorthCoord} {EastCoord} {SouthCoord}"
print(Command)

Options     = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine(Command))
gdal.Translate("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330_.tif", SubLayer, options=Options)

>>> Land_Cover_Type_1
>>> -a_srs '+proj=sinu +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m' -a_ullr 13.054073 50.0 31.127441 40.0
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\geo\script\hdf5_to_geotiff.py", line 21, in <module>
    gdal.Translate("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330_.tif", SubLayer, options=Options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 422, in Translate
    return TranslateInternal(destName, srcDS, opts, callback, callback_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\geo\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3381, in TranslateInternal
    return _gdal.TranslateInternal(*args)
TypeError: in method 'TranslateInternal', argument 3 of type 'GDALTranslateOptions *'
```

In [this script](https://blackmarble.gsfc.nasa.gov/tools/OpenHDF5.py), EPSG code is used but I only have PROJ4 and WKT formats. How can I use PROJ4 or WKT definitions with `gdal.Translate` function?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317/converting-netcdf-dataset-array-to-geotiff-using-rasterio-python/329141#329141

Comment: You can try: `rioxarray.open_rasterio` as well.

Comment: use +R not a,b .

Answer (score 0):

What you provide does not match the API (or it will not throw an error due `TypeError` e.g https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError)

Instead of providing a third argument using `gdal.TranslateOptions`, you can directly provide the args according to the API doc https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Translate

> Keyword arguments are :
> options --- return of gdal.TranslateOptions(), string or array of strings
> other keywords arguments of gdal.TranslateOptions()
> If options is provided as a gdal.TranslateOptions() object, other keywords are ignored.

So, try

```
gdal.Translate("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330_.tif", SubLayer, options=Command)
```

PS: I've already documented the way to provide options for `gdal.VectorTranslate` and the logic is similar for `gdal.Translate`. It may help you. If curious, you can take a look at [Issue to convert from PostgreSQL input to GPKG using Python GDAL API function gdal.VectorTranslate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397023/issue-to-convert-from-postgresql-input-to-gpkg-using-python-gdal-api-function-gd)

Comment: it took me a while but i think i solved my problem. Your explanation helped me to use gdal.Translate. However there was another problem, I realized that I needed to transform geodetic coordinates to projected coordinates. The script below somehow worked but

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version of my script. I still cannot understand how it worked, though.   I don't think I used the projected coordinates in the correct order.

```
from osgeo import gdal
from pyproj import Proj

Dataset     = gdal.Open("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330.hdf", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
SubDatasets = Dataset.GetSubDatasets()
SubLayers   = [SubLayer for SubLayer, _ in SubDatasets]

SubLayer    = gdal.Open(SubLayers[0], gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
SLName      = SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()['long_name']

proj4       = "+proj=sinu +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m"
crs_prj     = Proj(proj4)

ulcLat   = float(SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"])
ulcLon   = float(SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["WESTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE" ])
lrcLat   = float(SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["SOUTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE"])
lrcLon   = float(SubLayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["EASTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE" ])

lrcX, ulcY = crs_prj(lrcLon, ulcLat)
ulcX, lrcY = crs_prj(ulcLon, lrcLat)
print(ulcX, ulcY, lrcX, lrcY)

gdal.Translate("../data/MCD12Q1/MCD12Q1.A2001001.h19v04.006.2018142205330_.tif",
               SubLayer,
               **{"outputBounds": (ulcX, ulcY, lrcX, lrcY),
                  "outputSRS"   : proj4})
```

[image]