# Raster conversion from NetCDF to GeoTIFF changes data values

Tags: python, raster, rasterio, netcdf, rioxarray

I am trying to convert a NetCDF file to a GeoTIFF. I've followed the steps outlined in [Converting NetCDF dataset array to GeoTiff using rasterio Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317) and everything works fine. However, when looking at the underlying data, the values increase by an order of magnitude when the data is converted to a GeoTIFF. Here is an example using the following gridMET precipitation data (https://www.northwestknowledge.net/metdata/data/pr_2016.nc):

```
import xarray
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import rioxarray # Not used but package required to run script
# import netCDF4 # Not used but package required to run script

# read in NetCDF
xds = xarray.open_dataset('path/to/pr_2016.nc')

# Write first band to .tif
xds['precipitation_amount'][0].rio.to_raster('./pr_example.tif')

# Read new data with rasterio and convert nodata value
with rio.open('pr_example.tif') as tmp:
    rio_arr = tmp.read(1)
    rio_arr = np.where(rio_arr == 32767, np.nan, rio_arr)

# Look at difference between two arrays. 
# If they were identical, all value should be zero. 
xds_arr = xds['precipitation_amount'][0].values
diff = rio_arr - xds_arr

# Difference of ~500 mm/day between the two arrays
plt.imshow(diff)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Difference between plots]

In the resulting plot, all regions of the U.S. that had non-zero precipitation have values that are ~10x greater in the .tiff relative to the .nc file.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this information in the metadata `precipitation_amount_scale_factor=0.1`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Where did you find that metadata? I'm not able to find it when looking through `xds` metadata.

Comment: Actually, I found that this value is given in the rasterio raster under the `scales` attribute (`tmp.scales`). Thanks for pointing out the scaling factor!

Comment: Why don't you use rioxarray.open_rasterio to open the tiff? It will mask and scale for you if you pass in the mask_and_scale kwarg. https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html

Comment: I found that metadata with gdalinfo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @user30184 pointed out, there is a scale factor that is applied to the NetCDF when it is read with `xarray`. When opening the .tiff with `rasterio`, this scaling factor must be multiplied with the array to properly scale the values:

```
# Read new data with rasterio and convert nodata value
with rio.open('pr_example.tif') as tmp:
    rio_arr = tmp.read(1)
    rio_arr = np.where(rio_arr == 32767, np.nan, rio_arr)
    # Multiply by scaling factor
    rio_arr = rio_arr * tmp.scales
```